# Can non browser app use OAuth application code grant type

Tags: oauth, webapi, snapchat

We have a requirement to call Snapchat APIs from the non-browser application. These APIs use OAuth for authentication with a grant-type authorization code.

This grant type needs a redirect URI to authenticate with an external application and generate a code that can be used to create tokens.

We don't have a redirect URI as ours is a non-browser application that needs to pull(GET) data from Snapchat.

How do we generate tokens as we don't have to redirect URI? Is the autoriation_code grant type suitable for non-browser-based applications?

Refer Snapchat API Specifications for token generation:
https://marketingapi.snapchat.com/docs/#user-auth-via-redirect

Answer (score 1):

Your application doesn't have to be a browser, but it does have to support redirection to use the code grant type.  From the specification:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1

"The authorization code grant type is used to obtain both access
tokens and refresh tokens and is optimized for confidential clients.
**Since this is a redirection-based flow, the client must be capable of
interacting with the resource owner's user-agent (typically a web
browser) and capable of receiving incoming requests (via redirection)
from the authorization server**."

Depending on which stack your application is written in, there may be libraries available to support this.